# React-ChartJS-2. Not Rendering in PDFViewer

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-pdfrenderer

I want to render the chart generated by the Bar component inside the PDFViewer but it is not working. It will display an error "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item ". I just copied the example data from the [Chart JS docs][1]. It is working fine though if I put it outside of the PDFViewer. Is there a way around this?

```
import { PDFViewer, Document, Page, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'
const Stats = () => {
const labels = ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October"];
    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First Dataset',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };

    const options = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        },
    };
return (
        <div>
            <PDFViewer style={{ width: '100%', height: '600px' }}>
                <Document title='Library Statistics' size="A4">
                    <Page style={styles.page}>
                        <Text style={styles.body}>Statistics Goes Here:</Text>
                        <Bar options={options} data={data}></Bar> //not working
                    </Page>
                </Document>
            </PDFViewer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Stats;


  [1]: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
```

Comment: Is it supposed to work? I don't see any chart.js component for react-pdf... Even for adding basic html to pdf renderer you would need an adapter like [react-pdf-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-html)

Comment: @kikon Sorry I'm new to react and my first time using the pdf/renderer. I thought it would work since the chart is showing if I display it outside of the PDFViewer

Comment: Natively, it only works with its own [components](https://react-pdf.org/components); for others, including basic html it needs an adapter, and I'm afraid there isn't one yet for charts.js